# How to disable notifications from other apps in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-notification

I am developing an android launcher where one of the features snoozes all the other notifications, I have seen this, in an app called 'Morph', in the app, it takes you to Settings->Notification Access where you need to grant the app all notification access.

I was wondering, how can I do that with Flutter, and after being granted the notification access, how to use it to disable notifications from other apps in flutter.
Thanks!

**EDIT: This can apparently be done using `NotificationManager` with its `cancel()` in android dev so what can be the alternative for the same in flutter?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the existing plugin available could do the trick. Try to explore the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). You will be able to schedule notification or remove the notification. Check out the [features](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#-features) of this plugin.

> - Cancelling/removing notification by id or all of them

It was mentioned that the feature is available.